# How to split a string and count the parts?

Tags: jsp

How can I do the same as the following PHP snippet in JSP?

```
$to_len = count(explode(",",$to));
```

Basically, it splits a variable with the name `to` on delimiter `,` and then counts the parts.

Answer (score 1):

Using [JSTL functions](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnalg.html):

```
${fn:length(fn:split(to, ','))}
```

Another way is through scriptlets, but it is not recommended - `to.split(",").length()`